# Can I intervene to stop police brutality?

Tags: police, use-of-force

For example, in an [Eric Garner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Eric_Garner) type situation - if I see police on a guy's back. The guy is saying and demonstrating that he can't breathe. Can I physically pull or push the police officer, in order to save the person's life?

Comment: Whatever the law says in theory, in practice you will be restrained and arrested as well, so you will be unable to help. You might also have the police blaming your intervention for any bad outcome for the original arrested person.

Comment: Consider that you are encountering a police officer who apparently doesn’t have much respect for the law. That makes it very, very risky. You better have a lot of witnesses who are willing to stand up in court against a police officer.

Answer (score -3):

I've been wondering this for a while. I'm not very strong so i couldnt do much, but part of me thinks, "f*** it, i dont care what happens to me if it means saving someone from State terrorism," but then i wonder if me diving into the ring to help out would only make them more dangerous...like if i throw fists would they pull guns out? probably. and then who would they shoot? this white lady that attacked them or the black man they initially were brutalizing? so it's a tough scenario...and i dont have the answer. i guess at the end of the day, FILM EVERYTHING and try to get involved without making them more aggressive (like saying, "im a civil rights attorney. i have your badge number and if you dont stop im going to sue your ass.") or something. idk idk idk. so hard. but always do something. dont just watch or leave. blood's on your hands too then.